# Rails generators not generating the proper test templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, generator, minitest, specifications

My project lives here: https://github.com/jonesdeini/ICanHazSandvich

I'm getting setup using minitest-rails add I can't get the generators to generate the correct test templates.

from my application.rb:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :mini_test, :spec => true, :fixture => false
end
```

even with "g.test_framework nil" I still get the same test templates generated:

Output:

```
rails g model Foo
    invoke  active_record
    create    db/migrate/20120827160129_create_foos.rb
    create    app/models/foo.rb
    invoke    test_unit
    create      test/unit/foo_test.rb
    invoke      factory_girl
    create        test/factories/foos.rb
```

Even with "rails g model Foo --spec" the same files are generated.
I'm using rails 3.2.8 and ruby-1.9.3-p194

Thanks for you help!

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
 end
```

EDIT:

A pull request has been submitted for this issue
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/pull/68

Comment: Did you add minitest-rails to your Gemfile?

Comment: Yes sir, I've added my part of my Gemfile to the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `factory_girl_rails` gem. That railtie is assuming either `rspec` or `test_unit`, and its configuration is conflicting with your configuration. Here is how I would resolve this:

Change the dependency to the `factory_girl` gem in your `Gemfile` file:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
end
```

Configure your app to use FactoryGirl in your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :mini_test, spec: true, fixture: false,
                               fixture_replacement: :factory_girl
end
```

Well, that's not entirely true. How I would really resolve it is to remove FactoryGirl completely, but that's an answer to a different question...

Comment: Awesome, thanks! 

No love for factory girl? Do you prefer fixtures or something else?

Also, thank you for minitest-rails!

Comment: I prefer to create the objects I need. If you have a complicated setup then you should feel and eventually ease that pain by changing the design of your code. Factories tend to mask the pain and when you eventually feel the pain it will be much later in the lifecycle of your app and much more difficult to solve.

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. I was really confused wtf the generators were puking on me.

Comment: This solution is giving me a `factory_girl [not found]` error, although the alternative of using the `factory_girl_rails` gem overrides the `spec` option...

Comment: @blowmage you raise a good point.  Yet, the ability to abstract commonly repeated behavior is the reason we write software.  I'd just caution people against overly complex FactoryGirl factories, which *have the potential* to do as you suggest.  I totally agree, but I also remember hearing people make a similar argument for why they used assembly language rather than C.  LOL

Answer (score 1):

The problem of the `factory_girl_rails` gem forcing the use of `Test::Unit` has been fixed by the maintainers, however this has not yet filtered through to `rubygems.org`.

If you update your Gemfile to contain:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails.git"
end
```

it should all work nicely!