# Minitest-rails generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I'm using minitest-rails (https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails) and it works quite well. One problem though is that the generators are not working. Or rather, it seems to always invoke "test_unit" instead!

This is what my "test/minitest_helper.rb" looks like:
https://gist.github.com/3496814
(Notice that I override test unit there)

In "config/application.rb" I have this:

```
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie" ## Test Unit is not required!
```

Also this:

```
## application.rb
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :mini_test, :spec => true, :fixture => false
end


## Gemfile
group :test, :development do
  gem 'minitest-rails', git: "git://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails.git"
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'turn'
end
```

Still, when generating a model for example, I get this:
(The --spec doesn't actually matter. It generates the same stuff anyway)

```
rails g model Horse --spec
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20120828095404_create_horses.rb
  create    app/models/horse.rb
  invoke    test_unit                   ### Invoking test_unit??!
  create      test/unit/horse_test.rb
  invoke      factory_girl
  create        test/factories/horses.rb
```

If I just create the files manually minitest is working like a charm.

Is there anything else I need to do to make the generators work properly?

Using Rails 3.2.7 at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails generators not generating the proper test templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148611/rails-generators-not-generating-the-proper-test-templates)

Answer (score 1):

The problem of the `factory_girl_rails` gem forcing the generator configuration to `Test::Unit` has been fixed by the maintainers, however this has not yet filtered through to `rubygems.org`.

If you update your Gemfile to contain:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails.git"
end
```

it should all work nicely!

**PS:** You can also drop the `:fixture => false` from `application.rb` when doing this, as `factory_girl_rails` sets this for you.